# Return result from a parallelized for loop

Tags: r, foreach, parallel.foreach

I want to simulate data and at the same time perform analysis on those data 10000 times. Therefore I used a "for" loop in R to repeat the work 10000 times. Now I want to parallelize this tasks. For which I followed the following codes:

```
library(parallel)
library(doSNOW)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(3)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

progress <- function(n) cat(sprintf("task %d is complete\n", n)) # to check the progress of the work

setno<- data.frame(sample_no=c(1:10000))
no_of_samples<- unique(setno$sample_no)

simulated_data_list <- vector("list",length(no_of_samples))
analysis_result <-  numeric(length(simulated_data_list ))

foreach(i=1:10000,progress)%dopar%{
 tryCatch({
 simulated_data_list[[i]]<-  rnorm(100)# suppose we are simulating data 
 analysis_result[[i]] <-  1-pnorm(simulated_data_list[[i]][1])
 },error=function(e){cat("ERROR:",conditionMessage(e),"\n")})
}
```

But each time I do this, I find that the program is not simulating data (there is no problem in the program code as it runs normally without parallelization). I can't understand where is the problem in the above code. Can you suggest any better way to do this work?

Comment: 1. Your code is not reproducible `simulated_data_list[[i]]<-  some function to simulate data `; 2. Are you using seed in simulations?; 3. I would use `future` instead of `doSNOW`

Comment: @PoGibas I made it as reproducible. Can you suggest now?

Comment: You mean "there is no problem in the program code as it runs normally without parallelization" using foreach with simple `%do%` updates `simulated_data_list` and `analysis_result`?

Comment: @PoGibas without foreach and %do%

Comment: Yes, exactly! This is the way `foreach` returns it's result, it uses `return` and can't simply append to a provided list. Return single list from `foreach` with: `list(sim <-  rnorm(100);  1-pnorm(sim))`

Comment: @PoGibas You mean returning list( simulated_data_list[[I]], analysis_result[[i]]) each time?

Answer (score 1):

You have to `return` result from a `foreach` loop. For example:

```
library(parallel)
library(doSNOW)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(3)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

result <- foreach(i = 1:5) %dopar% {
    sim <- rnorm(2)
    list(sim , 1 - pnorm(sim[1]))
}
simulated_data_list <- lapply(result, "[[", 1)
analysis_result <- lapply(result, "[[", 2)
```

For example using simple `for` we can append to list, but `foreach` doesn't work like that:

```
dummyList <- list()
dummyList2 <- list()
foreach(i = 1:5) %dopar% {
    dummyList[[i]] <- rnorm(2)
}
for(i in 1:5) {
    dummyList2[[i]] <- rnorm(2)
}
lapply(list(dummyList, dummyList2), length)

[[1]]
[1] 0
[[2]]
[1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I understand. Somehow my own code is not working this this. But anyway, will check it.

Comment: @F.Privé his solution is correct. I had some problems inside my code. I fixed it.:)